# NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create when using "after_sign_in_path_for(resource)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently trying to write functionality for my quiz webapp that allows a user who reconnects to continue where they left off (possible reasons for reconnect are: because they lost their connection, or because they logged out unintentionally, or because they refreshed the page).

So I googled and found the solution, that I could write the method `"after_sign_in_path_for(resource)"` in the `application_controller`, and whatever I put in that method would be executed by Devise after a user logs in.

---

This solution works perfectly for when I try to render a static page (or even one of many static pages, depending on the "phase" parameter I save to my db).
But my app has 2 kinds of users:

- The "Teacher" who clicks links from static page to static page and
- the "Student", who has no control, but gets pushed new HTML whenever the Teacher clicks (pushed = HTML is received over ActionCable and replaces the current page)

So now what happens when a student logs in is this:

1. `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` is called: determines the user is a Student and calls
2. the `find_current_page` method in my `quiz_session` model: which checks the `phase` variable in my db and calls one of multiple methods on the serverside of my channel, e.g.
3. `resend_question_page` class method in my `IndividualUpdateChannel`: this method builds the html and broadcasts it to the Student.

BUT: instead of receiving and displaying the sent HTML the Student gets *"NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create - undefined method `student_url' for #"*. **In the logs it looks to me like 1., 2. and 3. are run, but then suddenly the app tries to redirect the Student somewhere? and fails.**

Here is the console output: https://pastebin.com/FKmHF4qS

```
...
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to student_#3: {:phase=>1, :answers=>["<div class='student-layout'>The call returns immediately without </br>waiting for the I/O to complete.</div>", {"ids"=>[9, 10, 11, 12], "current_question_index"=>1}]}
Redirected to
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 442ms (ActiveRecord: 103.6ms)
```

This is the full error message: 
[image: NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create browser screenshot]
And this is the rest of the trace: https://pastebin.com/psdyR2w2

And here is the code where the execution stops:

```
#app\channels\individual_update_channel.rb:
class IndividualUpdateChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  ...
  def self.resend_question_page(student)
    quiz_session = student.quiz_session
    new_answer_html = AnswerButtonCreation.new(quiz_session).create

    #This is where it stops
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("student_##{student.id}", phase: 1, answers: new_answer_html)
  end
```

I'm using Rails 5.0.2 and Ruby 2.3.3 with Devise 4.2.1 . This is my first Rails project, so please excuse if I got some best practices wrong. My googling of the inner workings of Devise didn't get me anywhere so I'd appreciate any help!

---

EDIT:
This is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :given_answers
  get 'students/set_quiz_session'

  resources :given_answers

  #change the sign_in and sign_out routes to /login and /logout
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login',
                                             sign_out: 'logout'},
             :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}

  resources :quiz_sessions, :answers, :questions, :quizzes, :courses

  # Setup static pages
  get 'teacher/quiz_start', to: 'pages#create_session', :as => :teacher_start_quiz
  get 'teacher/quiz_question', to: 'pages#show_question', :as => :teacher_question
  get 'teacher/quiz_question_result', to: 'pages#show_question_result', :as => :teacher_question_result
  get 'teacher/quiz_result', to: 'pages#show_quiz_result', :as => :teacher_quiz_result
  get 'teacher/home', to: 'pages#show', :role => "teacher", :page => "home", :as => :teacher_home

  get 'student/quiz_start', to: 'pages#join_session', :as => :student_start_quiz
  get 'student/home', :role => "student", :page => "home", :as => :student_home

  get ':role/:page', to: 'pages#show'
  root to: redirect('teacher/home'), :role => "teacher", :page => "home"

  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
end
```

Comment: what is meant by `student_url` can you share your `routes.rb`?

Comment: @Gabbar I added my routes